# Is it possible to get all documents in a Firestore Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update a value on all documents in a collection using cloud functions as they are dependent on the creation date, but looking through the Cloud Firestore Triggers examples it looks like all events are only able to access a single document. Is there a way to loop over all documents?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You'd typically use the Admin SDK for that in your Cloud Functions code. Once you have that, it's a matter of read the collection as usual. Check the node examples in the [firebase documentation on reading all documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection):

> ```
> const admin = require('firebase-admin');
>
> admin.initializeApp({
>     credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
> });
>
> var db = admin.firestore();
>
> var citiesRef = db.collection('cities');
> var allCities = citiesRef.get()
>     .then(snapshot => {
>         snapshot.forEach(doc => {
>             console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
>         });
>     })
>     .catch(err => {
>         console.log('Error getting documents', err);
>     });
> ```

Comment: don't forget to use the db.collection instead of db.doc, that is what people normally miss

Comment: Note that if the document does not exist (displayed as italic), it won't be returned. In case you want to get the reference for each document inside a collection (including the italic ones), you can call citiesRef.listDocuments() instead of citiesRef.get()

Answer (score 13):

Its possible.
if you want to get your document inside array. Without foreach.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});

const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('cities');
docRef.get()
.then(snapshot => {
    let arrayR = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
       return doc.data();
    }); 
    res.json(arrayR);        
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("got an error",error);        
})
```

Comment: I like that this solution sends the response in JSON format as well!

Comment: add `return` key word before `res.json(arrayR)` otherwise it induces an error while deployment

Comment: Awesome! Works fine here

Comment: Working locally fine BUT when i tried to deploy the function in Google Cloud Functions.Then it give me

```

"{"error":{"code":16,"details":"Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.","metadata":{"www-authenticate":["Bearer realm=\"https://accounts.google.com/\""]}}}"

```